# What are the benefits of using TLS with AWS DocumentDb?

Tags: ssl, devops, aws-documentdb

I'm migrating from MongoDb Atlas to AWS DocumentDB. I have docker image of app that uses MongoDb. It looks like that to use TLS with DocumentDb I need to add certificate to docker image - it wasn't required with MongoDb Atlas.

But what are the benefits of using TLS with DocumentDb ? DocumentDb can only communicate within VPC (it requires a SSH Tunnel to connect it from localhost). So traffic is 100% on AWS - so why use TLS if all AWS services are using HTTP internally ? For now my plan is to disable it, but would love to hear some arguments for.

Comment: As long a s I can remember there has always been a "most restrictive by default" approach when it comes to enterprise IT.

Answer (score 0):

Is part of the AWS Well-Architected framework ([security pillar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/security-pillar/sec_protect_data_transit_encrypt.html)) to have the ability to encrypt all communications, plus is an industry best practice to encrypt data in transit, even if is contained to a VPC.